# Coverting a string to an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have the following string: `"0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0"` stored in a variable `$monthvalues` and I would like to convert it to an array in this format:

```
'data' => [0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I tried with the code below:

```
$valuesarray = explode(",",$monthvalues);
$data = array('data'=>$valuesarray);
```

I'm not winning. Instead  I get

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 3 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 ) )
```

is it possible to just get `'data' => [0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0]`
without turning this into a multidimentional array?

The array should be in `'data'=>` and not `0=>`

Comment: What is the problem with the output from the `explode()`?

Comment: _I'm not winning..._ What errors do you get? Your code should work. I suggest you miss something like `explode(",",$monthvalues['data'])`

Comment: _..Instead I get_ This is actually exactly the result you are expecting. What is the problem with it?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. The result you're showing is indeed an array of values.

Comment: You do nothing to put it under that index - `$valuesarray = ["data" => explode(",",$monthvalues)];`

Comment: _“The array should be in 'data'=>”_ - and by what magic did you expect that to happen all by itself, considering that your input value does not even contain `data` anywhere …? This part you of course need to make happen yourself.

Comment: No magic. I'm just trying to solve this thing.  The issue is that the type of array I get is not the in the format  I would like it to be in. I've updated the question, hopefully it will make more sense.

Comment: I got it now. Sorry for asking a stupid question :(

Comment: If you want a secondary array under a  `data` key then you need a multi-dimensional array. Perhaps you're confused because `print_r()` prints the keys while you can omit them in array literals. That doesn't mean keys don't exist, it just means they're automatically generated.